# Realizar una consulta a una base de datos mediante AJAX y PHP

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando combinar una Beagle Bone Black (BBK) con el juego del dinosaurio de chrome. Ya he conseguido configurar las funciones de salto con una variable en concreto para que el dinosaurio salte cuando una variable que yo reciba cambie de 0 a 1 (por ejemplo, un botón de la BBBK). Lo que necesito ahora es recibir esa variable. Estoy haciéndolo mediante una petición a una base de datos.

Tengo en la BBBK la base de datos con una tabla sobre la que leeré el valor:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$userName = "usuario";
$password = "12345";
$dbName = "valores";
// Create database connection
$conn = new mysqli($host,$userName,$password,$dbName);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sqn="SELECT var1 from boton1;";
if ($sentencia = $conn->prepare($sqn)){

    $sentencia->execute();
    $sentencia->bind_result($comments);
    while($sentencia->fetch()){
    echo $comments;
    }
}
?>
```

Ya he conseguido que la petición sea correcta, pero ahora al implementar toda la función y cambiar el tipo de evento $(document).ready a una función la cual llamaremos nosotros, no está realizando el salto, el cual debería ya que en la base de datos, la variable var=1. Dejo aquí el trozo de la función, ya que todo el código JS del juego del dinosaurio no cabe.

```
<script>
       function check() {
        $.ajax({
        url:"getrequest.php",  
        success:function(data) {
          var value=data;
          if (value==1){
            jump();
          } 
        }
        ,error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 
        alert(xhr.status); 
        alert(thrownError); 
        }
            });
              }
          function jump() {
          var e = new Event('keydown');
          e.keyCode = 38; 
          document.dispatchEvent(e);
          }
         window.setInterval(check,1000);
</script>
```

Gracias de antemano.

EDITADO: ¡Ya funciona! El pequeño dinosaurio salta cuando se pulsa el botón de la PRU de la BBK.

Comment: Buenas, veo muy verde tu solución dices que haces cosas que son solo copy paste de otros ejemplos.... El ultimo ejemplo puedes descartarlo es WebSocket y tu usas TCP simple. Luego en tu ejemplo de comunicación de javascript no pones el puerto que en tu servidor es el 1337

Comment: He realizado una edición cambiando la manera de intentarlo Raúl

Answer (score 0):

Para llamar al ajax tienes que darle un evento, por ejemplo puedes hacer:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
    url:"getuser.php",  
    success:function(data) {
      hago_algo_en_àntalla()
    }
  });
});
```

Además te falta qué hacer si el ajax vuelve en forma exitosa.
Lo agregué en el código anterior.
Esto se ejecutará luego de que la página esté toda cargada.

Espero te sirva!

Comment: Eduardo, he intentado introducir tu código pero no me hace nada, no llama ni muestra nada.. he editado la pregunta para que veas cómo lo he implementado

Comment: Fijate si entre al success. Puede ser que este dando problemas el php y no vuelva en forma correcta. Esto lo puedes ver agregando luego del success: ,
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
      }.

Comment: me salta el error con una pantalla y un '0' en el centro... he editado el código para que veas lo que estoy ejecutando

Comment: Gracias Eduardo, no recordaba que PHP se ejecuta sobre apache, y estaba corriéndolo diréctamente..

Comment: Eduardo, la condición para que salte ajax tiene que ser siempre un evento? no podemos llamarlo nosotros a partir de una función?

Comment: Si, claro. Podes llamar a ajax de donde quieras. El ejemplo del document ready era solo un caso.

Comment: Ya funciona! Gracias Eduardo!

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que indicar que tipo de consulta vas a hacer, por ejemplo:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url:"getuser.php",  
success:function(data) {
  //Lo que necesites extraer.
});
}
```

Comment: Ya funciona Alex, la función check es la que llama al ajax. Muchas gracias de todas formas.